# Display 00000000 instead of 0 in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to display 0000000000 instead of 0 in a number field which is a type of bigint in sql database.
I am just able to display 0 instead of 00000000 since the data type is bigint. 0000000000 should display only for the ones that has ticket value as  0 ,other ticket number values should display the number that comes from database. I guess I need to pad but not sure where to use  in type script or in html.
Here is  my code where I get and set values. Kindly help!

```
     get numberValue(): number {
     return this.value.number; }:

       set numberValue(value: number) {
      setControlValue(this.get('number'), this.value.number, value);
    }

In html :
 <tbody  *ngFor="let ticket of form.tickets.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="number"/>
</td>`enter code here`
<tr>
<tbody>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've removed the C# and .NET tags since your question isn't related to those.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL datatype should not matter in your frontend code since the type is just *number*.
Angular supports pipes for formatting so you could just write a simple  [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) where you check if the value is 0 and replace it with the desired 0-padded value.

Edit (added example)

This could be your pipe definition

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
/*
 * Example:
 *   {{ 0 | myValueFormatter}}
 *   formats to: 00000000
 *   {{ 5 | myValueFormatter}}
 *   formats to: 5
*/
@Pipe({name: 'myValueFormatter'})
export class ZeroPaddingPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): string {
    if(value==0){
       return '00000000';
    }
    return number+'';
  }
}
```

Then you can use this pipe in your Angular component e.g. by calling

`{{ yourValue | myValueFormatter}}`
which should then display the formatted version of *yourValue.*

Comment: I am new to angular, It would be great if you can reply me with an example if possible. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I use pipe for input text type field like mentioned in my html code above? ```` <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="ticket.number| customnumber" formControlName="number"/> ```` this does not work for me..Please advise

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddwu3m) You need to write custom pipe

create pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'customnumber'
})
export class NumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(item: number): string {
        var result=item==0 ? "000000000":item.toString();
        return result;
    }
}
```

import in appModule in declaration

```
declarations: [ NumberPipe ],
```

then in html just put  like near your parameter `| customnumber`

in reactive form usage with `[value]`

```
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <input 
        [value]="myForm.get('number').value | customnumber"
        formControlName="number" 
      >
```

Comment: How do I use pipe for input text type field like mentioned in my html code above? ````      <input type="text" class="form-control"  [ngModel]="ticket.number| customnumber"  formControlName="number"/>    ```` this does not work for me..Please advise

Comment: in reactive forms you can use inside value. I edited answer